# How to set up play framework ApplicationLoader and Macwire to work with custom routes?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, playframework-2.0, macwire

I set up the application loader this way:

```
class MyProjectApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context): Application = new ApplicationComponents(context).application
}

class ApplicationComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with QAControllerModule
  with play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents {

  // set up logger
  LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach {
    _.configure(context.environment, context.initialConfiguration, Map.empty)
  }

  lazy val router: Router = {
    // add the prefix string in local scope for the Routes constructor
    val prefix: String = "/"
    wire[Routes]
  }
}
```

but my routes is custom, so it looks like:

the `routes` file:

```
-> /myApi/v1 v1.Routes
-> /MyHealthcheck HealthCheck.Routes
```

and my `v1.Routes` file:

```
GET    /getData    controllers.MyController.getData
```

so now when I compile the project I get this error:

> Error: Cannot find a value of type: [v1.Routes]
>       wire[Routes]

so im not sure how to fix this, does someone know how can I make the loader to work with this structure of routes?

Comment: Your file should be named v1.routes with a lower case routes.Then @adamw 's answer works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @marcospereira is correct, but maybe the code is slightly wrong.

The error is due to the `routes` file referencing `v1.routes` - this is compiled to a `Routes` class having a parameter of type `v1.Routes`.

You can see the generated code in `target/scala-2.12/routes/main/router` and `/v1`.

Hence to wire `Router`, you need a `v1.Router` instance. To create a `v1.Route`r instance, you need first to wire it.

Here’s one way to fix the above example:

```
lazy val router: Router = {
  // add the prefix string in local scope for the Routes constructor
  val prefix: String = "/"
  val v1Routes = wire[v1.Routes]
  wire[Routes]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to wire the `v1.Routes`. See how it is done manually here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Providing-a-router

This should work as you expect:

```
lazy val v1Routes = wire[v1.Routes]
lazy val wiredRouter = wire[Routes]

lazy val router = wiredRouter.withPrefix("/my-prefix")
```

ps.: didn't test it in a real project.

Comment: its not working :/ i get this error https://ibb.co/iHH99a and I did exactly as you wrote above (i know you didnt test it) and no success. also didnt really understand what to put in the Prefix..

Comment: also started a bounty :)